# Setup of my project doesnt work on other pcs

Tags: vb.net

I have publish a project and create a setup and in others pc's doesnt work how to include allfiles when install my project and not askin for any solutions

Example when i install it on another PC' it  i dont want to ask for sql server or something but run directly

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Your question, as it stands, doesn't have enough information for anyone to help you diagnose the issue. Read the [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page and update your question with more details like what errors you are seeing or what is expected versus what is happening.

Comment: Example when i install it on another pc. my project setup i dont want to ask for sql or any of these files. i want just when the setup is finished to run the application,

Comment: If you don't want to ask for any other files then don't. Of course, if you design an application that uses other components and you don't provide them then your application will fail. That should be fairly obvious. Please try providing ALL the relevant information IN YOUR QUESTION, i.e. NOT in comments. If your application is not working how you expect then explain EXACTLY what is happening and how that differs from your expectation. Questions that basically read "I want this, tell me how" are not acceptable here.

Comment: Example when i want to install it in another pc, i have to run SQL Server and then execute the database then run tmy project ?